# Django SQL OR via filter() & Q(): Dynamic?

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-q

I'm implementing a simple LIKE search on my Django website and what I currently use is the following code:

```
from django.db.models import Q
posts = Post.objects.filter(Q(title__icontains=query)|Q(content__icontains=query))
```

Where `query` is a string. This results in a `LIKE` SQL statement and works quite okay. Now I'd also like to split my search query into terms or words:

```
words = query.split(' ')
```

So `words` now contains a list of words, and I'd like to achieve an SQL statement similar to:

```
SELECT ... FROM foo WHERE `title` ILIKE '%word1%' OR `title` ILIKE '%word2%'
  OR `content` ILIKE '%word1%' OR `content` ILIKE '%word2%'
```

And in case there are more than two words I'd like the statement to grow listing all entries by every word.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Don't forget to sanitize your queries or you will be in the same situation that Boby Table's school was.

Comment: what about using fulltext search with djapian?

Comment: @the_drow: Django (or more correctly, DB-API) deals with that already.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
reduce(operator.or_, sequence_of_Q_objects)
```

Comment: Ah, sorry for comment, typo there. Removed. This seems to work, thanks so much, didn't know if this reduce() function and operator.or_

Comment: `reduce(lambda: q, w: q | Q(...=w), query.split(' '), Q())`, maybe too complex for one liner though.