# Django .filter on same option with multiple possibilities

Tags: django, filter

I have a model of objects. I also have a list of options to filter results with. I'm not sure if there is an easy way to filter the objects in the model such that any object that matches any of the items in the filter list is returned. For example:

```
# returns all users with name starting with 'P'
usersWithPName = User.objects.filter(name__startswith = 'P')
# 3 letters to filter User model with
filterList = ['P', 'T', 'R'] 
# ideally would return all users with name starting with either 'P', 'T', or 'R'
usersWithPTRName = User.objects.filter(name__startswith = filterList)
```

Is there any way to filter (in this case) the User model such that any object matching any one of the items in the filterList is returned?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This can be done with [Q objects](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects)

```
from django.db.models import Q
usersWithPTRName = User.objects.filter(Q(name__startswith='P') |
                                       Q(name__startswith='T') |
                                       Q(name__startswith='R'))
```

Also you can build Q filters at runtime:

```
filterList = ['P', 'T', 'R']
query = Q()
for letter in filterList:
    query = query | Q(name__startswith=letter)
usersWithPTRName = User.objects.filter(query)
```

Comment: Except that this assumes that there are a set number of items I'm searching for. The filterList is specifically done such that it can be of variable size. I need something that doesn't rely on hardcoded Q objects

Comment: @paradoz870 See second example

Comment: Thanks. That helped quite I bit. I used that in combination with Ignacio's suggestion of 'reduce()' above.

Comment: @catavaran : can this be done using an ```&```? Ive tried it out with no luck.

Comment: FYI: if you need to do something like this using ```&``` functionality check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11405044/django-orm-filter-using-a-list-of-objects-with-an-and-functionality)

Comment: In  my experience, if filterList is empty, then this will return all Users, rather than no users, so you probably need to check for that condition. I guess a newly constructed Q() is a filter that allows all records, but as soon as you "or" it with something, it becomes a filter that is equivalent to the thing you or'd it with, which was counter-intuitive to me.

Answer (score 2):

You can use python `reduce` and `operator` builtins:

```
import operator
from functools import reduce

from django.db.models import Q

values = ["blue", "green", "brown"]

# or condition
conditions = reduce(operator.or_, [Q(**{"categories__slug": value}) for value in values])

# and condition
conditions = reduce(operator.and_, [Q(**{"categories__slug": value}) for value in values])

queryset = queryset.filter(conditions)
```

Answer (score 0):

Two choices.

1. Include the first letter as a property in your model.
2. Use more advanced queries.

You can do this

```
class User( models.Model ):
    ... all the usual stuff ...
    @property
    def first_letter( self ):
        return self.name[:1]
```

Now can you filter with `filter( first_letter__in=('P','T','R') )`

The second choice is to build Django `Q` objects for your filter.

Start here: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=django+Q+objects

Comment: You can't filter on Python properties using the Django ORM.

Comment: Django won't let you use something other than field (or F object) in lookup.

Comment: I think the Django Q objects would be better but I am having some trouble figuring out how to combine two Q objects (and which ones) in order to obtain the proper result. What I need is, all objects that have a field `LIKE` any within a list. Given the above example, PATRICK, ROBERT, THOMAS, etc would be valid results. I can't seem to figure out the proper structure for the Q objects to do a "startswith any of P, T, R"

Comment: @paradoz870: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4147383/django-sql-or-via-filter-q-dynamic/4147416#4147416