# Django ORM: filter using a list of objects with an 'and' functionality 

Tags: django, orm

Newbie question...

Models:

```
Item(model.Models):
    ...
    attributes = models.ManyToManyField('Attributes', null=True)
    ...


Attributes(models.Models):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique = True)
    value = models.TextField()
    ...
```

I have a list of attribute objects `[attObj1, attobj2, attObj3, attObjN]` that I want to use when filtering the `Item` table. The following query works.

`items = Item.objects.filter(attributes = attObj1 and attObj2 and attObj3)`

***The problem*** is I need to dynamically create the query (ie: `attObj1 and attObj2 and attObj3... and attObjN`) as the amount of attributes in the list is unknown.

I tried using the following complex queryset **with no luck** ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5783588/django-filter-on-same-option-with-multiple-possibilities)). It returned an empty list.

```
attList = [attObj1, attObj2, attObj3]
query = Q(attributes = attList.pop(0))
for att in attList:
    query = query & Q(attributes=att)

items = Item.objects.filter(query)
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
items = Item.objects.filter(attributes__in=attList)
```

EDIT: 
You can also try chaining/multiple the filters

```
attList = [attObj1, attObj2, attObj3]
fitems = Items.objects.filter()
for att in attList:
     fitems = fitems.filter(attributes=att)
```

`fitems` are reduced to a set containing objects which have attributes in attList.

Comment: `__in` works as `Q(...) | Q(...)`, see question he wants `and`.

Comment: @Ahsan ohh yes! So multiple filters need to be applied. Have updated answer for that.

Comment: @Rohan Great work... you'd think there would be a more straightforward way of doing this similar to ```__in```.