# Django client side query construction

Tags: ajax, django, json, django-queryset

I'm making a pretty standard AJAXy (well, no XML actually) web page.  The browser makes a bunch of API queries that return JSON to run the site.  The problem is, I need to add to the API interface each time the page needs to do something new.  The new API interface is usually little more than a database query followed by mapping the returned objects to JSON.

What I'd like to do is to get rid of all that server-side duplication and just have the page make database requests itself (using the model interface), but  in a way that is safe (i.e. just read only ones).  I think this would amount to an interface for constructing `Q` objects using JSON or something like that, and then send that up to the server,  run the query, and return the results.  Before I go making my own half-broken architecture for this, I'm wondering if this has already been done well.  Also, is this even the best way to go about eliminating this duplication?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Search multiple fields of django model without 3rd party app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4487054/search-multiple-fields-of-django-model-without-3rd-party-app)

[Django SQL OR via filter() & Q(): Dynamic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4147383/django-sql-or-via-filter-q-dynamic)

[Generate a django queryset based on dict keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5350846/generate-a-django-queryset-based-on-dict-keys)

Just replace with `operator.and_` where appropriate.

Comment: Hm, ok, that's basically what I meant when I talked about making my own half-broken architecture, hoping someone had thought through things a bit more.  But it'll be pretty simple, looks like a lot of people think that's the right way to go.